# Android-Saving text that is being written in a SearchView

Tags: android, searchview

Im trying to get text that is being written on the searchView and save it to a variable that I'm going to use later. I know that SearchView has an OnQueryTextListener but I don't know where to use it to catch those events.This is what I'm trying so far.

```
 SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            Log.d("Debug", "text is submitted");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.d("Debug", "text has changed");
            return false;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
```

But I have no idea where to use this, right now it's being called in this part of the code that handles the search suggestions:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            Log.d("Debug", "text is submitted");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.d("Debug", "text has changed");
            name = s;
            return false;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    if (ContactsContract.Intents.SEARCH_SUGGESTION_CLICKED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        //handles suggestion clicked query
        String displayName = getDisplayNameForContact(intent);
        String displayPhone = getDisplayPhoneForContact(intent);
        name = displayName;
        phone.setText(displayPhone);
        searchView.setQuery(displayName, false);
        searchView.clearFocus();

    } else if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        // handles a search query
       name = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
       //name = (String)searchView.getQuery();
       searchView.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong about your usage?

Comment: @Luis Albertorio. Please clarify more what your issue is. We also have no idea what you want to achieve from your question.

Comment: I am not sure why you're setting that listener in onNewIntent, I would do it in onCreate probably, but as the other commenters, it's not clear what's your use case and what you pretend to achieve.

Comment: Oh sorry, well the name that is typed on the seachView will be saved to a variable to later be displayed on a textView. Right now, the user has to press submit or on a search suggestion so that the name is saved to the variable. But if the user presses away, for example to another TextEdit, the variable will remain empty.

Comment: oh wow just moving it to the onCreate fixed it, thank you @DanielOcampo

Comment: you're welcome. feel free to upvote me :D